# How do I install OSX Lion on Core Solo Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, osx-lion, mac-mini, xcode

I have a core solo Mac mini that was being used as an HTPC up until now. It's the only Mac I have, so I thought I might try to salvage it to do some iOS development. For that I wanted to upgrade to Lion and XCode 4. Apparently Lion will not install on a core solo, it requires at least a core 2 duo. I'd be happy to use Snow Leopard, but XCode 4 refuses to install on anything but Lion. How can I trick Lion into installing on this old Mac mini?

Or maybe is there some way to trick XCode 4.1 to installing on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely can't. Core Solo is a 32bit CPU, and Lion requires 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but you have to upgrade the processor to a Core2Duo first.

See here:

http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=249877

All in all, I don't think it's worth the hassle, but it is possible.